# org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

Getting error:

> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree

In jmeter when trying to import a jmx file recorded by blazemeter.

Answer (score 0):

Report a bug at blazemeter with full stacktrace, test plan and your version of jmeter